# load image from an array to an image view and show next or previous with flipper

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a static array.

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0
}
```

Now I have to show these images in image view one by one and with the help of flipper(or anything else) show the previous or next image.
First question how to load these images in image view.
It would be good for me if you can provide some sample code.
Thank you.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can display image using array like this way.

```
int id= mThumbIds[5];

youImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(id))
```